# LoopBack - how to log in a user created by loopback-component-passport

Tags: passport.js, loopbackjs, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

I follow this documentation and examples: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Third-party-login-using-Passport.html

At the moment I was able to create a user using a Google account.
Everything works fine, I have a new **user** in database and his **userIdentity**.

**user table:**
[image]

**userIdentity table:**
[image]

To log in a standard user, we can use **POST /users/login** endpint. After providing the correct data we get a **token**.

**The question is:**
How to log in the user provided by Google? And how can I get his **token**?

PS. I want to use this token in a frontend application. I am asking for help in understanding this process.

Comment: Please look this may help you `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788998/loopback-passport-mobile-login`

Comment: @IftekharDani Thank you for your answer, now I have a token, but I do not know how to pass it back to the application (res.redirect -> as url param?)... How to do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

For **social login** in **LoopBack + mobileApp**.

**I have added example for loopback  + ionicApp.**

1.**You need add Facebook SDK in your APP.**

2.**Add facebookLogin in App**

Example:

```
this.fb
  .login(["public_profile", "user_friends", "email"])
  .then(res => {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    const requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });


   var provider = 'facebook';
   var authSchema = 'oAuth 2.0';

   // Make a request to google api
   // to exchange refreshToken and accessToken with using google apis
   var accessToken = 'FROM FACEBOOK API';
   var refreshToken = 'FROM FACEBOOK API';

   // external id is your google or facebook user id
   var externalId = 'FROM FACEBOOK API';
   var email = 'FROM FACEBOOK API';

   var credentials = {};
   credentials.externalId = externalId;
   credentials.refreshToken = refreshToken;

   var profile = {};
   profile.id = externalId;
   profile.emails = [{type:'account', value: email}];
    let postData = {
      provider,
      authSchema,
      profile,
      credentials
    }

    this.http.post("http://you-api-url/socail-login", postData, requestOptions)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data); //here you get token set in localhost as current login done.
       }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  })
  .catch(e => console.log("Error logging into Facebook", e));
```

**Here create post request in loopback for login**

```
module.exports = function(app, router) {
    const UserIdentityModel = app.models.UserIdentity;
    const EndUser = app.models.EndUser;
    /*Api for third party  */

    router.post('/social-login', function(req, res) {


        if (!req.body.provider || !req.body.authSchema || !req.body.profile || !req.body.credentials) {
            res.status(501).send({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
            return;
        }
        UserIdentityModel.login(
            req.body.provider, req.body.authSchema, req.body.profile, req.body.credentials, { autoLogin: true }, ipAddress,
            function(err, loopbackUser, identity, token) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(501).send({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
                    return;
                }
                // token is access token for thig login
                res.json({ loopbackUser: loopbackUser, identity: identity, token: token });

                //return res.send(token);
            });

    });

};
```